# Using difference of average for identifying features in an image

Tags: matrices, average, image-processing

I'm working with this paper: *[Textural Features Corresponding to Visual Perception](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=4309999)*, by Tamura, Mori, and Yamawaki. 
There's a part where you have to calculate neighborhoods of one image (matrix of, for example $256 \times 256$) and those neighborhoods have to be $2^k$ size square.

> Step 1: Take averages at every point over neighborhoods whose sizes are powers of two, e.g., $1\times1$, $2\times2$, $\cdots$, $32\times32$. The average over the neighborhood of size $2^k\times2^k$ at the point $(x,y)$ is $$A_k(x,y)=\sum_{i=x-2^{k-1}}^{x+2^{k-1}-1}\sum_{j=y-2^{k-1}}^{y+2^{k-1}-1}f(i,j)\big/2^{2k}$$ where $f(i,j)$ is the gray-level at $(x,y)$.

Ok that's great.

Then I have to calculate a difference:

> Step 2: For each point, at each point, take differences between pairs of averages corresponding to pairs of non-overlapping neighborhoods just on opposite sides of the point in both horizontal and vertical orientations. For examples, the difference in the horizontal case is $$E_{k,h}(x,y)=\left|A_k\left(x+2^{k-1},y\right)-A_k\left(x-2^{k-1},y\right)\right|.$$

Let $A(0,0)$ be the point where I want to calculate the difference.

If I use $A(0,0)$, I will go out of bounds on the second member.

Do you think it's an error? There's nothing about the '$h$' parameter anywhere as well.

$k$ could be $0, 1, 2 \dots$

Comment: Perhaps it's h for horizontal.  When you do differences, there will be an edge, of width $2^{k-1}$ where you can't do it exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Michael suggested, $h$ is for horizontal. You'll also have vertical difference 
$$
E_{k,v}(x,y) = |A_k(x+2^{k-1},y) - A_k(x-2^{k-1},y)|
$$
I think that they take $E_k = \max(E_{k,h},E_{k,v})$ and then maximize over $k$.

> I will go out of bounds on the second member.

Yes you will, if $(x,y)$ are close to the boundary. The authors admit as much:

> boundary strips of a picture within the width of the largest
>   operator size $2L$ cannot be processed properly.

They offer no remedy to the boundary effects. One possible solution is to extend the image to a larger square by setting the color of every exterior pixel equal to the color of the image pixel nearest to it.

Comment: It's a good answer, thanks. But I don't understand yet, if I take neighborhoods of k = 3, how to calculate the E1,h or E2,h or v... how could I do it ?

Comment: First you calculate $A_k$. Can you do that?

Comment: of course. Then ?

Comment: Then you subtract and take absolute value. I don't see what  the trouble is.

Comment: The trouble are those variables (h and v)... what should I do with them ?

Comment: They are not variables. They are just pieces of notation. In your code, you can use descriptive names like `Evertical` and `Ehorizontal`. In a math paper, these get compressed to $E_v$ and $E_h$, since mathematicians hate multi-letter names.

Answer (score 0):

It looks ok to me.

[image]

In the diagram I have taken $(x,y)$ to be $(5,4)$, so I am comparing two squares, one yellow, one orange, either side of $(x,y)$. That is the $k$ case. Then there is a similar comparison for the $h$ case. Of course, you run into trouble if you are too close to the border, but that is inevitable.